# Blogger edit html element with javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, blogger, element

I have a problem with updating HTML element http://www.hororsf.iz.rs/. The element class is "date-header"

I tried Jquery function triggered on load

```
$( "date-header" ).replaceWith( "<h2>New heading</h2>" );
```

I tried this in Jquery:

```
 <script language='text/javascript'>
 function cirtolat(){   
 $(&#39;date-header&#39;).each(function() {
 var text = $(this).text();
 $(this).text(text.replace(&#39;петак&#39;, &#39;doll&#39;)); 
 });

 }
 </script>
 <body onload="cirtolat();">
```

And this in Javascript

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(/hello/g, 'hi');
```

I used another words this is just example. I tried this also: (every example provided here I put inside onload function).

```
var str = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML; 
var res = str.replace("Microsoft", "W3Schools");
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
```

I first tried does this onload function work with alert and it worked. I need this to work on blogger platform so I don't have access to server side access only client side with jquery or javascript.

If I had access for sever side I would find wordpress language folder where he stores date array and replace all values with needed.

So I need to replace all occurrences of strings

> децембар/новембар/октобар/септембар/август/јул/јун/мај/април/март/фебруар/јануар/

with

> decembar/novembar/oktobar/septembar/avgust/jul/jun/maj/april/mart/februar/januar

days:

> понедељак/уторак/среда/четвртак/петак/субота/недеља/

with

> ponedeljak/utorak/sreda/četvrtak/petak/subota/nedelja/

I don't understand why standard methods of javascript and jquery I used on non-blogger sites don't work.

Comment: `"date-header"` so you have some `<date-header></date-header>` element? Or you meant to target `".date-header"`

Comment: The link you provided... how is it relevant to your question?

Comment: Its date-header element in html. <h2 class='date-header'><span><data:post.dateHeader/></span></h2> its code in bloggger xml file which  is returning the date when post is published. But is uses its own api not php. If it was in  php it would be easy.

Comment: Thats the website of my client where i need to change cyrilic to latin for dates.